# Getting a value from Dataset and pass it to Globals C#

Tags: c#, dataset, global

I want to get a value from a dataset of a database. I created a login form and when I login, it shows me the ID number of the user and the username in a MessageBox.

When I try to pass the ID value to a Globals variable, I get 0. I am using a for-loop and while-loop. Everytime when I pass that value to the other form, I still get 0. I don't know what the issue is in my code.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
int i ;
HabibisGrll.Globals.cashier = i;

private void but_log_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (tbx_username.Text == "" || Tbx_Password.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide UserName and Password");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                //Create SqlConnection
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tbl_Cashier where FName=@username and Password=@password", con))
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbx_username.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Tbx_Password.Text);

                    HabibisGrll.Globals.sss = tbx_username.Text;

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapt.Fill(ds);
                    con.Close();
                    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;


                    //while(i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
                    //{
                    //    MessageBox.Show("ID Number : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + Environment.NewLine + "USER : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1], "User INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    //    i++;
                    //}

                    for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ID Number : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + Environment.NewLine + "USER : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1], "User INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

                    //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        HabibisGrll fm = new HabibisGrll();
                        fm.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple things wrong here, for example it is a bit strange you are using a for loop when its really only 1 record, but anyway, heres what I think you should do, changing the least possible code:

```
private void but_log_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (tbx_username.Text == "" || Tbx_Password.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide UserName and Password");
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        //Create SqlConnection
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tbl_Cashier where FName=@username and Password=@password", con))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbx_username.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Tbx_Password.Text);

            HabibisGrll.Globals.sss = tbx_username.Text;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
            if (count == 1)
            {
                HabibisGrll.Globals.cashier = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("ID Number : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0] + Environment.NewLine + "USER : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1], "User INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Hide();
                HabibisGrll fm = new HabibisGrll();
                fm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you saved me ^^ i didnt think about that at al

Comment: I updated your code to avoid the Error , the right code `HabibisGrll.Globals.cashier = Convert.ToInt32( ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]);` thanks alot ^^

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 invokes internally Int32.Parse, as long as value is not null, so it should be (almost) the same. Now that I see it again, I missed a ToString() there, cause itemarray is an array of objects, not strings, so what you did is perfect yes. Also, If you want to add validation you could use TryParse, to validate the values (that is, to make sure the dataset objects can convert to integers).
Your original code did not work cause you are saving the index of the row, which will always be 0 cause its only 1 record. I fixed that and saved the right value in your static class.